# How to use PrimeIcons with table/grid paginator

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am trying to build and the font awesome is large so I am trying to completely replace it with PrimeIcons

```
<p-table #dt id='incidents-grid' [value]='incidents' [totalRecords]='totalRecords'
    expandableRows='true' [responsive]='true' dataKey='IncidentId' *ngIf='visible'
    [rows]='5' [paginator]='true' [rowsPerPageOptions]='[5,10,50]'
    [lazy]='true' (onLazyLoad)='loadIncidentsLazy($event)' [loading]='loading'>
```

The paginator doc does not show anything.

Comment: Explain your issue a bit more. What is the step you are following  to use prime-icons? Any Image or code you can share ?

Comment: I am using Angular 6 and primeicons 1.0.0-beta.10 and primeng 5.2.4 per package.json.  I have replaced 'fa fa.edit' with 'pi pi.pencil', etc...  I removed @import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"; from style.css and then the paginator for the above p-table has -- 1 2 -- (missing < >), and any dropdowns are missing the down caret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to the PrimeNG:

> "primeng": "^6.1.4",

and the problem is solved.

Hey DirtyMind: You referenced a different version and that triggered the solution.

Comment: I am glad you got the solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I created your scenario i used primeNg 6:

- Step 1: npm install primeicons --save
- Step 2: Import the prime icons in style.css or angular.json

I added the in style.css like below :

```
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css';
@import '../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

And use Icon anywhere in your app:

```
<p-tabView class="tabdetail">
       <p-tabPanel header="Basic Info" leftIcon="pi pi-calendar">
       </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

And it is working as expected.
Make sure you are importing primeicons path in style.css correctly. I think you might miss importing icons.

Comment: My style.css has the following: `@import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "primeng/resources/themes/flick/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
`

Comment: Hey DirtyMind: The declared PrimeIcons classes pencil, plus and trash on buttons display just fine. The paginator and drop-downs do not display icons correctly. On the paginator and drop-downs controls the icons are not referenced.

Comment: I am able to see Icons properly in pager and dropdown properly. Might be because of your Primeng vs ^5.2.4. I downgraded my app to 5.2.4 and getting lot of erros so not able to replicate